# Popups in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, popup, panel

How should I open a popup window from a swf?

My method - create another panel and overlay on the original swf.
The problem is that the size of the original swf is small compared to the size of the popup window.

**No JS call allowed** which does not allow me to use `window.open` javascript call.

**Update**: I need to be able to communicate with this popup window as well. This eliminates opening a new window using `navigateToURL` method.

Comment: I hope you're using your powers for good or for awesome. Pop-ups should be avoided whenever possible. Are you opening another webpage from flash? usually that allows you to specify the window target.

Comment: yes...I am using my powers for good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to communicate with the popup, you can still use the navigateToURL and use [SharedObjects](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) to pass the message between the movies. Or maybe a [socket](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/Socket.html) connection to 127.0.0.1 and a port for each movie. Or a [LocalConnection](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html), like gthmb said.

Answer (score 3):

you'll have to use `navigateToURL` and set the target to `'_blank'`

ie)

```
navigateToURL( new URLRequest('http://my.useful.content.not.spam.com/page.html'), '_blank')
```

you'll have to take care of the layout in the `page.html`

Comment: Updated the question...I cannot use the `navigateToURL` method.

Comment: its either `window.open` or `navigateToURL`. thats it as far as spawning a new window. if you need to communicate back and forth between the 2 swfs, you will have to look into the `LocalConnection` object.